# Use .jrxml file for Swing application

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

Actually I am using `.jrxml` file for web application, but now I need to use same in Swing.

Is it possible?  Can I use `.jrxml` file for Swing application?

### JRXML E.G.

```
SELECT R.FUND_TRANSFER_TRACE_ID AS Stan_ID, FS.SERVICE_NAME, R.MOBILE_NUMBER,CASE WHEN     C.MIDDLE_NAME IS NOT NULL 
THEN (C.FIRST_NAME +' '+C.MIDDLE_NAME+' '+C.LAST_NAME) ELSE (C.FIRST_NAME +'  '+C.LAST_NAME) END AS CUSTOMER_NAME,
R.FROM_ACCOUNT, R.TO_ACCOUNT, R.AMOUNT, R.SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE, R.RECORDED_DATE AS   TRANSACTION_DATE,FTD.FONEPAY_TRACE_ID, 
FTC.RESPONSE_CODE AS CANCELATION_RESPONSE_CODE, FTC.RESPONSE_MESSAGE AS   CANCELATION_RESPONSE_DESCRIPTION,FTC.RECORDED_DATE AS CANCELED_DATE, 
FTC.REMARKS 
FROM FONEPAY_TRANSACTION_CANCELLATION FTC 
JOIN FONEPAY_TRANSACTION_DETAILS FTD ON(FTD.ID=FTC.FONEPAY_TRANSACTION_DETAILS_ID) 
JOIN REQUEST R on(FTD.REQUEST_ID=R.ID)
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER C ON(C.ID=R.CUSTOMER_ID) 
JOIN FONEPAY_SERVICE_DETAIL FSD ON(R.FONEPAY_ID=FSD.ID) 
JOIN FONEPAY_SERVICE FS ON(FSD.FONEPAY_SERVICE_ID=FS.ID)  
WHERE 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),R.RECORDED_DATE,121)
     BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),$P{startDate},121) and     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),$P{endDate},121)
      and $P!{queryStr} AND FTD.FONEPAY_TRANSACTION_STATUS='REVERSAL_SUCCESS'
ORDER BY R.RECORDED_DATE DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but I went many tutorials and blogs. Could not solve. Will you please elaborate.

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Is it same procedure like web application  to generate pdf ? Can I use same classes and so on.  Please see my edited question where I am providing query which is implemented on `.jrxml`  file.

Comment: In theory, the jrxml should be portable, but they way you generate it might be slightly different.  Obviously, you need to provide some kind of data source to fill the report and this you will have to create based on where the report gets it data from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JRXML file is the "source" of your report, you need to get it compiled first...

```
protected static JasperReport compileReport() throws JRException {

    String sourceName = "/path/to/your/.jrxml";
    String destName = "/path/to/where/you/want/your.jasper";
    JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(sourceName, destName);
    return (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(destName);

}
```

Once you have the compiled report, you need to fill it...

```
 Map<String, Object> mapParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(5);
 // Fill in your parameters...
 JRDataSource dataSource = ...; // Create your data source
 JasperPrint filledReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, mapParameters, dataSource);
```

Once it's filled, you can export it...

```
System.out.println(" --> Exporting to PDF");
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, filledReport);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.START_PAGE_INDEX, 0);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "your.pdf");
exporter.exportReport();

System.out.println(" --> Exporting to Excel");
JRXlsxExporter excel = new JRXlsxExporter();
excel.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, filledReport);
excel.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.START_PAGE_INDEX, 0);
excel.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "your.xlsx");
excel.exportReport();

System.out.println(" --> Exporting to HTML");
JRHtmlExporter html = new JRHtmlExporter();
html.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, filledReport);
html.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.START_PAGE_INDEX, 0);
html.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "your.html");
html.exportReport();
```

Take a look at [View and Print Reports](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_view_and_print_reports.htm) for more details about providing a print preview and printing.

Note: We've had issues with the Print Preview component and ended up writing our own (based on the available source), but it might have begin fixed since then...

Answer (score 3):

You can surely use jrxml files in swings. I have used it so many times In my application. I'm developing ERP solutions using an open source tool Adempiere.

It is developed using swings here it is widely using jrxml for reporting purpose.

Refer the following link it may be helpful:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/524537/example-java-program-call-jasper-report